# OpenMP for MinGW w64?

Tags: gcc, mingw, openmp, mingw-w64

Are there any OpenMP binaries out there for the MinGW-w64 GCC compiler (Windows)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is  [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) (Windows) and  [sezero's Personal Build](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/) (Linux and Windows).

---

*update 2012/11:*

**Distribution       Host OS**

[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)            Cygwin, Darwin, Linux and Windows  
 [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download)                Windows  
 [MinGW-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/)      Windows

Comment: Ah! The personal builds are great. Thanks! :)