# How to make OpenMP work with MinGW-64 under Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, 64-bit, openmp, gcc4, mingw-w64

### The Scenario

I am developing an application in C99 ANSI C that uses [OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org) and [GMP](http://gmplib.org/). It's natural habitat will be a linux machine with plenty of cores, so there's basically no big trouble there, but for reasons I do not want to debate here, I have to develop under Cygwin on a 64 bit Windows machine.

When I use the 32 bit version of gcc, something, somewhere, goes horribly wrong and the application is about 60 times slower than a very crude single-threaded version, when it should in fact be faster by a factor that equals the number of CPU's. It makes it impossible to work with. I really don't know what is causing this; Anyway, I have decided to use the 64 bit version of MinGW instead, that'd be `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.5.3` and his friends, to be precise.

A side note: I am sure that the slowdown is not a flaw in my multithreading, the multithreaded application works correctly and faster on the linux machine.

### The actual Problem

Setting up GMP was easy, it can be compiled from source without any trouble and then works like a charm. *Compiling* the following easy example with `-fopenmp` also works like a charm:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        mpz_t t;
        mpz_init(t);
        mpz_set_si(t,omp_get_thread_num());
        # pragma omp critical
        { 
            gmp_printf("Hello From GMP'd Thread %Zd!\n",t); 
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        mpz_clear(t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, executing it gives me

```
$ ./test
test.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532826/openmp-for-mingw-w64), but I would like to make this work without downloading any binaries other than those from an official Cygwin repository. Since my example compiled with the `-fopenmp` switch, I am convinced that this should also be very much possible.

Can someone help me with that? Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Does it work when linked statically with `-static`?

Comment: Gives me exactly the same error message.

Comment: Could be a compiler or linker error given that name of `?`. Could you try and get a newer GCC build?

Comment: I had already updated cygwin, so this should be the latest build there is.

Comment: Ok you don't want to discuss it. Still, allow me to ask why Cygwin. I have some quite flawless experience here with MSys and MinGW-w64 (TDM build) using Console2 command line interface. Using this combination also openmp works like charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that "error while loading shared libraries: ?:" means that cygwin does not know where to find `libgmp-10.dll` and/or `libgomp-1.dll`.

Both DLL are required according to [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

[image: dll]

Your program worked after I added the directory that contains both DLL to my `PATH`:

```sh
#$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -fopenmp -o w64test gmp_hello.c -lgmp
#$ file ./w64test.exe
./w64test.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows

#$ ./w64test.exe
/home/david/SO/hello_openmp/w64test.exe: error while loading shared
 libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
 directory

#$ ls /cygdrive/c/dev/cygwin/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/*mp*dll

/cygdrive/c/dev/cygwin/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/libgmp-10.dll
/cygdrive/c/dev/cygwin/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/libgomp-1.dll

#$ export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/dev/cygwin/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/

#$ ./w64test.exe
Hello From GMP'd Thread 1!
Hello From GMP'd Thread 0!
```

**note**

I compiled and installed `gmp-5.0.5` with the following commands:

```sh
./configure --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw  --enable-shared --disable-static
make -j 2
make check
make install
```

---

**update**

Your program also works with cygwin  "GCC Release series 4 compiler".

```sh
#$ g++ -fopenmp -o cygtest gmp_hello.c -lgmp
#$ ./cygtest.exe
 Hello From GMP'd Thread 1!
 Hello From GMP'd Thread 0!

#$ g++ -v
 Target: i686-pc-cygwin
 Thread model: posix
 gcc version 4.5.3 (GCC)
```

You might need to install the following [packages](http://cygwin.com/packages/):

- libgmp-devel (Development library for GMP)
- libgmp3      (Runtime library for GMP)
- libgomp1     (GOMP shared runtime)

Comment: That's perfect! Not finding the DLL's was exactly the problem. Also, the native 64 bit application with threading now runs faster than the singlethreaded version! Thank you so much for this great, very detailed answer.